# VPN Error "916, The interface is in a disabled state"

Tags: vpn

I have an ISA Server 2006 Server acting as a VPN server and it is working fine for all users.

However, there is one particular user who gets an error “916, the interface is in a disabled state.”

A similar error is also logged in the event log of the ISA Server

In Active directory, the user is a member of the "Domain Guest" groups.  Other members of this group are able to VPN in fine so I don't think it is a permissions thing.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Is the problem user based or machine based? Have them try on another laptop. I suspect Joshua may be on to the right answer

Answer (score 1):

I know, with the same problem, I had to reinstall the VPN client. The problem was a corrupt file. That may not fix it, though.

Answer (score 1):

After raising a support incident with Microsoft, the problem is solved in a rather bizarre way.

The user login in Active directory matched the name of an IPSEC Demand Dial interface I had set up which was disabled.  Enabling the demand dial interface resolved the problem.

Probably a bug in the RRAS software but at least I have a work around for now